# Discrepancy in Cubic Spline Interpolation, R & matlab

Tags: r, matlab, cubic-spline

I am trying to replicate the spline() function in matlab using the spline() function in R's splinefun {stat}s package, without having full access to matlab (I don't have a licence for it). I am able to input all of the necessary data into R that would be present in matlab, but my spline output is different than matlab's by an average of .0036 (maxdif is .0342, mindif is -.0056, stdev is .0094). My main question is, how does matlab's formula compare to R's, and is that where my calculation discrepancy might come from?

The first part of my code is feeding the excel spreadsheet into R, then calculating the necessary variables to get tau and quick delta. After this, I run the spline calculation and then rotate the output for the purposes of exporting back into excel. Below is the essential script, plus some data to try out to see if there is something flawed in my calculation. I use spline(natural), as it returns the closest values to matlab's model.

```
#establishing what tau is for quick Delta calculation
today<-Sys.Date()
month<-as.Date(5/1/2016)
difday<-difftime(month,today,units=c("days"))
Tau<-as.numeric((month-today)/365)
Pu<-as.numeric(1.94)
Vol<-as.numeric(.4261)
#Pf is the representation of my fixed strike prices, the points used for interpolation
Pf<-c(Pu-.3,Pu-.25,Pu-.2,Pu-.1,Pu,Pu+.1,Pu+.2,Pu+.25,Pu+.3)
qDtable<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=length(Pf),nrow=length(month)))
colnames(qDtable)<-c(Pf)
rownames(qDtable)<-format.Date(month)
#my quick Delta calculation & table as a result
qD<-data.frame(pnorm(log(Pf/Pu)/(Vol*sqrt(Tau))))
Qd<-t(qD[1:24,1])
qDtable[1,]=c(Qd)
#setting up for spline interpolation
qDpoint<-as.numeric(qDtable[1,1:24])
ncsibyPf<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=length(Pf),nrow=length(month)))
colnames(ncsibyPf)<-Pf
rownames(ncsibyPf)<-format.Date(month)
qDvol<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=14,nrow=2)
colnames(qDvol)<-c("",0,.05,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,.95,1)
rownames(qDvol)<-format.Date(month)
qDvol[2,2:14]<-c(.59612,.51112,.46112,.45612,.44612,.42612,.42612,.42612,.42612,.42612,.42612,.42612,.42612)
#x is the quick Vol point
x<-as.numeric(qDvol[1,2:14])
#y is the vol at the quick Vol point
y<-as.numeric(qDvol[2,2:14])
ncsivol<-data.frame(spline(x,y,xout=qDpoint,method="natural"))
nroutput<-t(ncsivol[1:24,2])
ncsibyPf[1,]=c(nroutput)
```

The essential data points for this spline run are all included (I think), and everything should line up correctly. Thank you for your help ahead of time!

Comment: You are using a natural cubic spline (`method="natural"`); Matlab's [spline](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html) command computes not-a-knot cubic spline. It doesn't look like `splinefun` supports not-a-knot; the closest method I see is "mff", but that one still looks different. ... By the way, Octave is free and its `spline` command should be compatible with Matlab's.

Comment: I may have to give Octave a go, then. I wonder' is it possible to edit the splinefun code to more closely match that of the not-a-knot method?